Is the proposed solar sailing race course possible?
This is an idea that's been banging around a couple of universes in my head for quite some time, the idea is to have solar sail racing yachts that have to traverse an asteroid field. This could be interesting enough but this field is not natural, would be nice if it looked like it was though, it has been built and engineered to make races more challenging and spectacular. The idea of this engineering would be to create currents, gusts, and doldrums in the natural particle winds as they pass through the field. Some of the "asteroids" will deflect charged solar wind particles, some absorb them, such that the path of the particles through the field is neither straight nor particularly predictable. This field would be quite close to it's parent star so particle density is as high as possible.
My question is twofold; can this be done by creating passive system(s), and can the system(s) used to do it make it appear natural to purely optical observation?
The "passive" part of the question refers to the field being made using whatever technology suits but afterwards needing no further energy or material inputs to continue it's function of channeling the particle winds coming from the star in unpredictable ways that require piloting skill and intuition to navigate. Having the racecourse identifiable as a technological artifact would, most importantly, be aesthetically displeasing to the creators and would potentially give racers too much optical information about conditions within the race field, thus lessening the challenge. The course will not be raced by the creators nor by anyone they care about, they are motivated to make racing conditions as difficult as possible as a matter of prestige both as the creators of the field and for the creators of the racers who will later be its victims. The racers themselves have some interest in surviving as difficult a course as possible and winning as their victory may mean the continuation of their gene line.
To clarify, because I should have said this to start with, the racers may be humanoid, or possibly just brains in a jar, but whatever they are they are far from human.

@JBH We can effect the flow of charged particles (which is what the vast majority of solar wind is composed of), we've been doing it at the Joe public level for decades. The science-based tag is entirely justified, the scale of application is vastly different here but the technology is familiar.

Do you mean we've had the ability to make (e.g.) sunglasses for decades? Or that we can block sunlight with bricks? That's not at all relevant on the scales you're discussing. But let's return to my core issue. What problem are you trying to solve? By "passive system" do you mean the use of orbital mechanics vs. thrusters? Or can the thrusters be hidden such that the participants don't particularly notice them? I honestly don't know what the problem is you're trying to solve.

@JBH No I mean we've been making high power electromagnetic fields to manipulate charge particles with pinpoint accuracy for decades in a number of household appliances, this is a huge but less stringent application of charged particle manipulation but we've been manipulating such particles since the middle of last century. What I'm asking is could a particle manipulating maze be created in the form of a natural looking asteroid field. I've explained exactly what I mean by passivity, read the whole question.

I've read the question several times, Ash, and I've no doubt that you understand it. Its your belief that it's clear for everyone else I'm challenging. A microwave oven doesn't imply the ability to create a star, quasar, pulsar, or magnetar, which is what's implied by "The 'passive' part of the question refers to the field being made using whatever technology suits but afterwards needing no further energy or material inputs to continue functioning."

@JBH The field can be made using whatever techniques are needed, nowhere did I mention the star being part of the racing set up beyond being the power source for the ships using it, where are you getting an artificial star from? Sorry if that sounds rude I'm just super confused.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I'm getting "artificial star" from the need to push an array of solar-sail ships across a large enough region of space that they can be spread out along with various objects bigger than they are with enough space between them to permit maneuverability combined with the need to be "passive," which you define as self-sustaining after whatever technology has kickstarted it.

Let's assume instead that you have a variety of projectors along with blockers and manipulators in the course such that no overarching energy source (aka star) is required. Such sources must be of sufficient mass that moving one or more (for safety, all) ships doesn't significantly move the source - but that wouldn't be "natural." So I'm back to star, quasar, pulsar, magnetar.

@JBH The orbit of Mercury experiences more than 4 times the particle density we experience at 1AU and a small body that could pass for an asteroid should melt before it reaches its solar Roche Limit so the race track can be significantly closer than that. Assuming a pared down racing craft totaling a metric tonne half pilot, hull, and very minimal life support and half sail then modern human light-sail technology would give roughly  1G of acceleration at 1 AU, 4 at Mercury, magnetic sails would be even more efficient than that, you don't need an artificial particle wind source, at all.

@JBH I think I understand what you're getting at, the particle wind as an artificial part of the racing field as opposed to the field being a later addition to an existing solar system, does my edit make it clearer what I'm getting at?

I posted a frame challenge. Part of the problem is that you appear to be combining two goals, one of which isn't relevant. (a) Can I achieve this goal? and (b) Is this possible? It's the later that isn't relevant, but due to its inclusion, it's muddied what you're trying to achieve with the former - assuming I've understood the underlying issues of your question. Frankly, I think this would have been better asked as two separate questions. The first asking, "I want to do this race, what must exist to rationalize it?" and then the second asking how to make the resulting course look "natural."

Solar sails work by using the pressure of the light emitted by the star. Any self-respecting star will output the vast overwhelming majority of energy in the form of light, not charged particles; for our own sun, the pressure exerted by light on a solar sail is many orders of magnitude larger than the pressure exterted by the solar wind. Apparently, the so-called solar sails in the question work differently...

@AlexP Reflective solar sails only use light pressure but there are two other methods of harnessing solar wind listed in that article both of which rely on charged particles.

I would be concerned about the asteroid sparseness of known asteroid belts. Due to time scales, distances, and precision needed heavy use of automation would be expected. Through with the sparseness setting a course like there are no obstetrical will get a ship through without incident with very good odds.

This is a Frame Challenge
I understand that your civilization can...

Create objects of sufficient technology, mass and characteristics such that those objects can project, block, and/or manipulate stellar wind.

Place these objects such that the pilots of solar-sail ships can race.

The goal of the creators of the race course is that the course look natural.1


Science doesn't know how to actually do any of that, despite aspects of those behaviors appearing in kitchen microwaves and particle accelerators. So, we must depend on a basic worldbuilding axiom:

A sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic — Arthur C. Clark.

One can do anything with magic, and so:

Blocking stellar wind is possible and intrinsically passive.

Redirecting stellar wind is possible but not intrinsically passive and can only be done on the scales imagined by the question (in my opinion) via substantial (meaning planetary strength) magnetic fields or gravity. A passive condition can only be achieved by moving (if not creating) planetary mass. No known science-based method of creating magnetic (much less gravitational) fields that can redirect solar wind on this scale exists, but can be extrapolated from a simple microwave. Nevertheless, if the goal is to look natural, then only a planet (or a dense planetary mass) will do.

Projecting stellar wind is possible, but requires accelerated mass on a substantial scale for this purpose. That means a significant power source and a reservoir of mass to achieve the effect no matter how narrowly or efficiently projected. Enough mass and energy must exist to permit any possible combination of events during the race to happen. This isn't natural or passive (as defined by the question) at all.


However...

A sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic — Arthur C. Clark.

Since you're relying on Clarkean magic to create the race course in the first place, it's no stretch of the imagination that the same Clarkean magic can be used to make the objects "passive" and look "natural" to casual observation.

1 This is actually a nonsensical goal. Space, insofar as science-based understands it, is incredibly vast and incredibly empty. So much so that every probe humanity has sent through its own asteroid field has cruised through it without so much as a scratch. Any asteroid field dense enough to be worthy of a race would (astronomically) quickly coalesce into a planetoid. Thus, any race course worth racing wouldn't be "natural" in any sense of the word other than, perhaps, all the objects looking like giant rocks hanging in space. Hollywood has been fooling the casual observer in this way for about a century.

The field strength of a planetary magnetosphere is quite low, even though the total field volume is vast. The point about asteroid field density is on the nose though, even with magnetic fields as strong as materially possible the object field density can't be high enough for them to interact to the necessary degree while looking anything but artificial and requiring massive artificial maintenance.

The strangest thing about this question is that it assumes that the vehicles use the solar wind for propulsion instead of the light emitted by the star. Our solar sails use the light, because that's where almost all of the energy is. The second strangest thing is that the question assumes that somebody, anybody, can place a bunch of rocks in orbit around a star and they will stay together without careful control; they won't.

In space nothing is standing still, everything moves around following its own orbit.
The very fact that an ensemble of bodies keeps maintaining a certain configuration over time would shout "artificial" after the first moment of surprise, like a sort of space Las Vegas.

Why would they maintain a formation? That makes the course the same for every race no challenge there. I was envisioning chaotic motion, like I said an asteroid field, just one with strange effects on the solar winds, not a rigid structure. Or are you saying that the effects would require a rigid structure? If so why?

L.Dutch, does this question make sense to you? What do you think the problem is Ash is seeking help for?

@JBH "Can a distribution of n bodies be difficult to navigate because of X and at the same time appear to be naturally occurring and not artificially made?"

And does the answer, "any civilization posessing a technology that would allow the construction of said bodies such that intentional navigation is difficult can obviously cause them to appear natural to the observer" make equal sense?

@JBH I would say so

Now I understand what you were driving at too, in order to function that much mass would have to be stationary and somehow locked to keep existing.

"I was envisioning chaotic motion, like I said an asteroid field" Asteroid fields are not chaotic, though. It's exceedingly unlikely that an observer would ever see as many as two asteroids simultaneously with the naked eye. If you're constructing your own movie-dense field in a small volume (no more than a planet, say), any that aren't flying in fixed formation will have a few hours at most before they're only visible with telescopes. Unless you enclose them in a bubble or tether them with invisible bungee cords, asteroids simply won't do what you seem to be asking for.

Granted, if you're launching them all yourself, you COULD set a few thousand on wildly diverging orbital planes such that every X years (our asteroid belt has an orbital period of between 3-6 years) one particular volume of space will be very crowded, astronomically speaking, with objects moving in different directions. Still not truly chaotic; you could calculate a clear path in advance with pen and paper math. But potentially exciting in a navigational sense.
